# Very strange behaviour with UTF-8

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8

How can I echo a sql text field into a paragraph?

My code does puts the text in but changes the accents like `á` to this -> `�`. 
I tried adding UTF-8 in the header and removing it.

Removing UTF-A makes the sql content is ok but all the content outside the paragraph messes up.

I checked the DB was using (UTF-8-unicode), The files were saved with UTF-8

Any ideas on what might be wrong?

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

<textarea class="texto" name="textoarticulo"  id="textoarticulo" form="formarticulo" placeholder="Texto del art&iacute;culo...">
 <?
    echo $row['txt4'];

 ?>
</textarea>
```

Comment: What do you mean by accents? what character is that?

Comment: á <- a with an accent

Comment: See "Black Diamonds" in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's important that your *entire* code has the same charset to avoid issues where characters displays incorrectly.

Here's a little list of things that has to be set to a specific charset.

**Headers**

- Setting the charset in both HTML and PHP headers to UTF-8

  - PHP (*PHP headers has to be placed before **any** output: PHP echo, whitespace, HTML!*):

    ```
    header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
    ```
  - HTML *(HTML-headers are placed within the `<head>` / `</head>` tag)*:

    ```
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    ```

**Connection**

- You also need to specify the charset in the *connection itself*.

  - PDO (specified in the object itself):

    ```
    $handler = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=database;charset=utf8', 'username', 'password');
    ```
  - MySQLi:  (placed directly after creating the connection, `$mysqli` is the connection object)

    ```
    $mysqli->set_charset("utf8"); // OOP style
    mysqli_set_charset($mysqli, "utf8"); // procedural style
    ```
  - MySQL (**depricated**): (placed directly after creating the connection)

    ```
    mysql_set_charset("utf8");
    ```

**Database**

- Your *database* and its tables has to be set to UTF-8. Note that charset is *not* the same as collation.

  You can do that by running the queries below once for each database and tables (for example in phpMyAdmin)

  ```
  ALTER DATABASE databasename CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
  ALTER TABLE tablename CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
  ```

  *Caution...*  There are various different situations that need different `ALTERs`.  [*Details Here*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll#fixes_for_various_cases) .  Doing the wrong `ALTER` is likely to make things worse.  -- Rick James

**php.ini specification**

- In your `php.ini` file, you should specify the default charset for your platform, like this

  ```
  default_charset = "utf-8";
  ```

  *(This is in essence the same as doing `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');` on all pages)*

**File-encoding**

- It's also important that the `.php` file itself is UTF-8 encoded. If you're using Notepad++ to write your code, this can be done in the "Format" drop-down on the taskbar. You should use UTF-8 w/o BOM.

Should you follow all of the pointers above, chances are your problem will be solved. If not, you can take a look at this StackOverflow post: [UTF-8 all the way through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through).

Comment: Thank you soo much, specifying charset on DB connection did it!

Comment: Good thing it solved your issue! Nevertheless, all of these steps should be applied to ensure that your code has the right charset. :)

Comment: Caution:  Those `ALTERs` may further corrupt the stored data.  It takes more analysis to decide whether to use them or a "2-step alter".

Comment: @RickJames Very true, although the answer was intended for a clean/fresh setup - perhaps it should've bene more clear. Feel free to edit the answer if you think it can be improved.

Comment: I added "Caution..." to your answer.  It includes a link to the various cases.