# Saving special letters (ü, č, ž..) to mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, database, collation

I can't save some special letters like german umlaut (ü) or croatian letters (ž,š,č) to the MySQL database.

This is what I have done so far:

1. Database collation is set to utf8_general_ci
2. Table collation is set to utf8_general_ci
3. Row collation is set to utf8_general_ci
4. In html meta tag is set to:
   `<meta http-equiv='content-type'content='text/plain;charset=utf8_general_ci'>`
5. In html form I've set the attribute `accept-charset="utf8_general_ci"`
6. in PHP I've set headers: `header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf8_general_ci');`
7. in PHP I've set `mysql_set_charset ( "utf8_general_ci", $link );`

I've been trying to solve this for days.. I also tried with `utf8_unicode_ci`.

What am I missing?

Comment: Don't confuse [database charset with collation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-database.html)

Comment: Your charsets should be `utf8` (someplaces it needs to be `utf-8`), `utf8_general_ci` is not a charset.

Comment: `utf8_general_ci` is used only in MySQL, in PHP header and HTML meta tag, use utf-8 only.

Comment: thanks for pointing that out. I've changed it to utf-8 in both html and php, but in db i still get: Å¾ for ž, Ã¼ for ü and so on..

Comment: @mirta Have a look at this one http://stackoverflow.com/a/33906476/4535200

Comment: See "Mojibake" in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored .